# Insert data from a grid and dropdown menu into SQL Server database with vb

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to insert a logged in user's medicine and details (PateintId, MedicineId, PharmacyId, Doctor Id, Date Ordered) and the date approved column would be edited by another user later.

When the user clicks the select command and chooses a pharmacy from the dropdown box and clicks order this will update the `Order_pres` table. The code I am currently working on does not work - can anyone please help?

I need the `e.command` in the grid to select the medicine, the patient from the session, their doctor (that is a foreign key in doctor table). The pharmacy will be selected from the dropdown and I also need the date to update when `btnconfirm` is clicked.

Code currently working on:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    If e.CommandName = "UpdateMedicine" Then
        Dim MedicineID As Integer = Integer.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())

        Dim strPatientId As String = Session("PatientId").ToString
        Dim strMedicineId As String
        Dim strDoctorId As String
        Dim strPharmacyId As String
        Dim strDateOrdered As String


        Dim query As String = String.Empty
        query &= "INSERT INTO Order_pres (PatientId, MedicineId, PharmacyId, "
        query &= "                     DoctorId, [Date Ordered])  "
        query &= "VALUES (@PatientId,@MedicineId, @PharmacyId, @DoctorId @DateOrdered)"

        Using conn As New SqlConnection("SurgeryConnectionString"), _
              comm As New SqlCommand(query, conn)
            With comm.Parameters
                'It's good practice to explicitly declare your parameter types 
                'I'm assuming "Id" fields are really integers. If that's wrong, adjust the types here to match the database
                .Add("@PatientId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(strPatientId)
                .Add("@MedicineId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(strMedicineId)
                .Add("@PharmacyId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(strPharmacyId)
                .Add("@DoctorId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(strDoctorId)
                .Add("@DateOrdered", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(strDateordered)
            End With

            Try
                conn.Open()
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                lblconfirm.Text() = "Order Placed"
        Catch(ex as SqlException)
                lblnoconfirm.Text() = "Order not placed"
            End Try
        End Using
    End If

      End Sub
```

The grid:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Select" CommandName="UpdateMedicine" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("MedicineId") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Purpose" HeaderText="Purpose" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Instrcutions" HeaderText="Instructions" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The dropdown, btnconfirm and label:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropPharm" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlPharm" DataTextField="Pharmname" DataValueField="Pharmname"></asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Button ID="btnconfirm" runat="server" Text="Confirm" />

<asp:Label ID="lblconfirm" runat="server" Text="your order has been placed"></asp:Label>
```

Code for grid:

```
    Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim conn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Laura\Final_proj\App_Data\surgerydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")
        Dim cmdstring As String = "SELECT md.MedicineId, md.Name, md.Purpose, md.Instrcutions  " +
                                    "FROM Patient pt INNER JOIN prescription pr ON pt.PatientId = pr.PatientId  " +
                                    "INNER JOIN medicine md ON md.MedicineId = pr.MedicineId Where pt.PatientId  = @PatientId"
        Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable()
        Dim da As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmdstring, conn)
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@PatientId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(Session("PatientId").ToString())
        conn.Open()
        da.Fill(dt)
        conn.Close()

        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    If e.CommandName = "UpdateMedicine" Then
        Dim MedicineID As Integer = Integer.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())


    End If
End Sub
```

Hopefully someone can help I have been trying desperately to get this to work

Kind regards

Comment: When you say "does not work", any error messages? What are the symptoms of this "does not work"? Have you made sure that when you step through the code you actually get into the `Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand...` sub?

Comment: @Jeroen I am fairly new to vb and I have a number of build errors I'm not sure how to add the drop down and .click function to this and was hoping if anyone had an example

Comment: RE: @laurajs " I have a number of build errors", make changes in small chunks and compile often, this way you know where things go wrong and can reverse changes (CTRL+Z) or fix them. Writing a large(ish) program in one go and then asking people to fix compile errors is lazy.

Comment: Sorry guys I will delete this post if there is no way to fix but I have genuinely tried so hard

Comment: Like @JoelCoehoorn said, first make sure you address the issue with the column names containing spaces. After that, go through the build errors one by one.

Comment: sorry @Jeroen I am a little confussed - do you mean there are issues with my column names on my grid?

Comment: @laurajs Nope, in your INSERT query. `Date Ordered` is not a valid column name and `@Date Ordered` is not a valid variable name.

Comment: Sorry @jeroen I had put that into the question inccorectly, didn't realise there was a space... With this insert query though is it valid to record the date or is that a something different that needs added

Comment: If you are storing that date in a dateline column I see nothing wrong with it (at a cursory glance). But what build errors are you getting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115119/discussion-between-laurajs-and-jeroen).

Comment: I have updated my code as seen above in the question - but I am seeing the follwoing error  a blue line under  `(ex as SqlException)`  and in the error box End of statement expected - when I have added an End try

Comment: `Catch ex As SqlException` in VB no parentheses are needed (or valid for that matter)

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of errors here. You'll need to address these one at a time. The first one I noticed is you need to account for the spaces in your column names:

```vb
Dim query As String = String.Empty
    query &= "INSERT INTO Order_pres (PatientId, MedicineId, PharmacyId, "
    query &= "                     DoctorId, [Date Ordered])  "
    query &= "VALUES (@PatientId,@MedicineId, @PharmacyId, @DoctorId @DateOrdered)"

Using conn As New SqlConnection("SurgeryConnectionString"), _
      comm As New SqlCommand(query, conn)
    With comm.Parameters
        'It's good practice to explicitly declare your parameter types 
        'I'm assuming "Id" fields are really integers. If that's wrong, adjust the types here to match the database
        .Add("@PatientId",  SqlDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(strPatientId)
        .Add("@MedicineId", SqlDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(strMedicineId)
        .Add("@PharmacyId", SqlDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(strPharmacyId)
        .Add("@DoctorId",   SqlDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(strDoctorId)
        .Add("@DateOrdered", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(strDateordered)
    End With

    Try
        conn.open()
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        lblconfirm.Text() = "Order Placed"
    Catch(ex as SqlException)
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error Message")
    End Try
End Using
```

Comment: thank you very much for taking time to help me out with my code. I am a beginner and really appreciate your contribution to my learning, I am just getting abit confussed because I also have a drop down to select a pharmacy - would this go on the e.command or the btn.click ? many thanks :)